# Problem with \SIlist with two values and list-final-separator = {, }

Tags: siunitx

First and foremost, thanks to Joseph Wright for developing and maintaining `siunitx` package.

I have a problem with `\SIlist` macro. The desired result:

> 3.23 (dd, *J* = 3.9, 0.9 Hz, 1H).

and I'm using this code:

```
\num{3.23} (dd, \emph{J} = 3.9, \SI{0.9}{\Hz}, 1H).
```

It works fine but I thought I could  use `\SIlist` macro and eventually automate things a bit:

```
\num{3.23} (dd, \emph{J} = \SIlist[list-units=single,list-final-separator = {, }]
{3.9;0.9}{\Hz}, 1H)
```

I get the following result:

> 3.23 (dd, *J* = 3.9 and 0.9 Hz, 1H)

A list of three or more values works OK:

```
\num{3.23} (ddd, \emph{J} = \SIlist[list-units=single,list-final-separator = {, }]
{3.9;0.9;0.1}{\Hz}, 1H)
```

> 3.23 (dd, *J* = 3.9, 0.9, 0.1 Hz, 1H)

Any ideas? Thank you.

`siunitx` version 2013/02/01 v2.5p.
Win7, MiKTex 2.9

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `list-pair-separator`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\SIlist[list-units=single,list-final-separator = {, }, list-pair-separator= {, }]
  {3.9;0.9}{\Hz}

\end{document}
```

I'd probably use `\sisetup` to do this globally.

Comment: Thank you, Joseph. What is the best placement for global option (after `\begin{document}`?

Comment: @HubertMuchalski In the preamble (before `\begin{document}`) would be my preference.

Answer (score 1):

Have had exactly the same question, funny. This is what I am using in my preamble to set most things right for chemists work with `siunitx` ;)

```
\sisetup{
    detect-family,
    alsoload        = synchem,
    list-units      = single,
    range-units     = single,
    range-phrase    = --,
    list-pair-separator= {, },
    list-separator  = {,},
    list-final-separator = {,},
    per-mode        = fraction,
    exponent-product = \cdot
    }
```

Comment: `alsoload` is a version 1 option: it's deprecated in v2 and you really should define any non-standard units yourself [I'm a chemist too, and I define things like `\Molar` :-)] Also, some of your settings are 'personal choice', rather than answering the question.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or select your code and hit Ctrl+K.