# Why do you need both list-pair-separator and list-final-separator in siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

I wanted to translate the automatically written words in the `siunitx` package to Danish (at least the parts I use) and found the answer to [Problem with \SIlist with two values and list-final-separator = {, }](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98965/problem-with-silist-with-two-values-and-list-final-separator).

I used the following code to do it:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}  
\usepackage[range-phrase={ til },
        list-final-separator={ og },
        list-pair-separator={ og },
        detect-all,
        separate-uncertainty=true,
        group-digits=false]{siunitx}


\begin{document}

\SIlist{8;9;10}{\keV}

\SIlist{8;10}{\keV}

\end{document}
```

and got the output:

[image: SIlist]

My question is (probably for Joseph Wright): Why do I need to state both `pair` and `final` (list separator)? Is it just me who wants the same separator in both cases? I thought (from the name of the option) that `final` was all I needed and that `pair` could be used if I wanted them to differ. Wouldn't that be a better option?

(I'm just asking, not criticising.)

Comment: I guess it's for coping with the “Oxford comma”; according to this practice you write “apples and oranges”, but “apples, pears, and oranges”.

Comment: Also known as [serial comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the language/editorial style, the 'filler' used in a list of two items:

```
<item one> <pair separator> <item two>
```

and the filler used in a longer list:

```
<item one> <list separator> <item two> <final separator>
```

may be different (*e.g.* in English with the 'Oxford comma' the first case is just '`and`' but the second case is ',`and`'). The only way to cover that in an interface is to differential between the two: trying to say 'you can set only one' and have inheritance is asking for trouble!

Comment: Entirely unrelated to TeX, of course!

Comment: 'inheritance' was the word I was looking for... So the point is that inheritance is messy, I guess. Also I didn't think of the (Oxford) comma notation since that's not a problem in Danish as far as I'm concerned. Is there another place I should have posted this question (non-TeX forum)?